# C++ array function error: Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector

Tags: c++, void

I am receiving the following error: Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector. Can anyone advise on how to fix this issue? I am receiving the error in the void GetData function at the bottom on the line that reads " vals[valCount] = value; ". Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

//function declarations
void GetData(double vals, int valCount);
void Sort(double vals, int valCount);
double Variance(double vals, int valCount);
double StandardDev(double vals, int valCount);
double SqRoot(double value); //use for StandardDev function

//function definitions
int main ()
{
    double sum = 0,
        variance = 0,
        standardDev = 0,
        vals = 0;

    int valCount = 0;        //number of values to be processed

    //ask user how many values
    cout << "Enter the number of values (0 - 100) to be processed: ";
    cin >> valCount;

    //process and store input values
    GetData(vals, valCount);

    //output
    cout << "\nValues in Sorted Order: " << sum;
    cout << "\n\nThe variance for the input value list is: " << variance;
    cout << "\nThe standard deviation for the input list is: " << standardDev;
    cout << "\n\nPress any value to exit this program\n" << endl;

    return 0;

}

//process and store data
void GetData(double vals, int valCount)
{
    int value; valCount = 0;

    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> value;

    while (value != 0) {
        vals[valCount] = value;
        valCount++;

    cout << "/nEnter a value: ";
    cin >> value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `vals` is not an array/vector: `double vals`.  Perhaps it should be `double *vals`.

Answer (score 1):

vals is a double which means it can only hold one value. You need an array or vector. Also in GetData you loop while value isn't 0 but you already got valCount from the user, so you should probable use a for loop to loop this number of times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

//function declarations
void GetData(double* vals, int valCount);
void Sort(double* vals, int valCount);
double Variance(double* vals, int valCount);
double StandardDev(double* vals, int valCount);
double SqRoot(double value); //use for StandardDev function

//function definitions
int main ()
{
    double sum = 0,
        variance = 0,
        standardDev = 0;
    double vals[100];

    int valCount = 0;        //number of values to be processed

    //ask user how many values
    cout << "Enter the number of values (0 - 100) to be processed: ";
    cin >> valCount;

    //process and store input values
    GetData(vals, valCount);

    //output
    cout << "\nValues in Sorted Order: " << sum;
    cout << "\n\nThe variance for the input value list is: " << variance;
    cout << "\nThe standard deviation for the input list is: " << standardDev;
    cout << "\n\nPress any value to exit this program\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}

//process and store data
void GetData(double* vals, int valCount)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < valCount; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a value: ";
        cin >> vals[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, but now I am receiving an error here:
 //process and store input values
    GetData(vals, valCount)

"No matching function for call to 'GetData'"

Comment: I added an "&" in the main function when referencing the GetData function and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @larry718 you shouldn't need an "&".  Did you declare vals as `double vals;` or `double vals[100];`?

Answer (score 0):

**vals** in your code is not an array.
Hence, you cannot do **vals[x]**, which means accessing the element at xth index.